# Angular 2 mentions : How to update an array bind to a directive after an api call

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, mention

I'm using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-mentions.
So MY code is this :

```
.ts file :
  ngOnInit():void {
    this.items.push("temp Name")
    let __this = this
    this._userService.getAll(1).subscribe(res => {
      res.users.forEach(function (a,b) {
        __this.items.push(a)
      })
      console.log(__this.items)
    })
  }
```

.html file :

```
<input type="text" [mention]="items"  >
```

The array is been updated and have the data from api but the directive [mention] is bind to the old array contain values that been  initialized statically at start !

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try sth like this

```
<input *ngIf="items.length > 0" type="text" [mention]="items">
```

or set other flag which would be true after you fetch your data.

It could work because it will render input after you fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the whole reference of your array after adding items. After you finished pushing to array new data you have to do something like that:

```
this.__items = this.__items.slice();
this.ref.markForCheck();
```

What it means if there is a case where any thing inside your model has changed but it hasn't reflected the view, you might need to notify Angular to detect those changes ( detect local changes) and update the view.

What you can also do is implementation of DoCheck interface. The default change detection algorithm looks for differences by comparing bound-property values by reference across change detection runs. ngDoCheck gets called to check the changes in the directives in addition to the default algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

[mention]="users.length>0 ? users : []"

use this condition for mention. It will set the value only if users array is loaded.